# Authoritative resource for toxic foods for rats

Tags: diet, safety, poison, rat, treats

Is there any authoritative resource for what foods are toxic for what animals? I'm getting conflicting information from around the web.

In this case, I'm specifically interested in rats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ASPCA has a useful [list of foods to avoid](http://www.aspca.org/pet-care/animal-poison-control/people-foods-avoid-feeding-your-pets) on their website, and as far as I can tell the information is consistent with what I've learned from vets and other reputable sources. Also see their [list of poisonous plants](http://www.aspca.org/pet-care/animal-poison-control/17-poisonous-plants). If there's a specific food that you've received conflicting information about, you might want to ask about that specifically so we can give more detailed information.